# Writing decimal value with round to 8 places using c# datatable into Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, decimal

I am trying to write decimal values rounded to 8 places into Excel in C# using datatable.

There are no errors, but the output in Excel does not show 8 decimal places.

I have tried many suggestions from the internet, nothing has worked so far.

I have tried setting the data column types.

```
dt.Columns[6].DataType = typeof(decimal);

dr[6] = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(inpRow[20]), 8);
```

[image: Datarow column type]

[image: Datacolumn type set to decimal]

Output in the Excel, if value is `124.73` then output should be `124.73000000`.

Comment: What you want is to adjust how a decimal is displayed, you do NOT want to change the decimal value itself. To change the display you need to ajdust the format used to turn a decimal value into a string, `StringFormat`. eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mt73hR

Comment: How is the `DataTable` related to your excel at all? You have not shown how you export it to excel and if the excel columns have formats.

Comment: @RandRandom I don't want to convert into string as the output excel needs to have numbers for calculations from another process

Comment: @TimSchmelter I add this datarow to a datatable : dt.Rows.Add(dr); and then save it the excel : wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Securities transaction upload");

Comment: `I don't want to convert into string..` - again I am talking about the DISPLAY, what is displayed will ultimatily boil down to a string. A decimal/datetime and so on, if displayed is a string - so everytime you DISPLAY a value it will be formated into a string eg. datetime is formated to MM.dd.yyyy or MM.dddd.yy or .... - and thats where you have to make changes you have to declare how your decimal value should be displyed - in excel cell simply change the numeric format.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-f27f865b-2dc5-4970-b289-5286be8b994a - or vba: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat | https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=de-de&rs=de-de&ad=de

Comment: @RandRandom Made minor change to your code on the lab: Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString("#0.00000000")) as N8 was adding commas in the numbers. But in the excel it shows warning on the field : Number stored as text. Not sure if the system accepts this value from excel, need to check. Thank you for your time.

Comment: excel is now showing a warning because you didn't change how it will be displayed but you went ahead and changed the underlying value, decimal to string - don't really want to stress it out further than I already did, but you really really should only change how it will be displayed - if my hunch is correct and you are using `ClosedXML` to generate the excel maybe this helps: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Styles-NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

OP did mention the following line, how the excel is generated

```
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Securities transaction upload");
```

which makes me believe OP is using `ClosedXML`, see the following example from their github page

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet

If that is correct, the following lines can be added to format all columns with the type of `decimal`.

```
for (var index = 0; index < dataTable.Columns.Count; index++)
{
    var dataTableColumn = dataTable.Columns[index];
    if (dataTableColumn.DataType != typeof(decimal))
        continue;

    var rangeWithHeader = ws.Column(index + 1).AsRange().RangeUsed();
    var rangeWithoutHeader = ws.Range(rangeWithHeader.FirstCell().CellBelow(), rangeWithHeader.LastCell());
    rangeWithoutHeader.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#0.00000000";   
}
```

Full sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();

    var dataTable = GetTable("Information");

    // Add a DataTable as a worksheet
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);

    for (var index = 0; index < dataTable.Columns.Count; index++)
    {
        var dataTableColumn = dataTable.Columns[index];
        if (dataTableColumn.DataType != typeof(decimal))
            continue;

        var rangeWithHeader = ws.Column(index + 1).AsRange().RangeUsed();
        var rangeWithoutHeader = ws.Range(rangeWithHeader.FirstCell().CellBelow(), rangeWithHeader.LastCell());
        rangeWithoutHeader.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#0.00000000";   
    }

    wb.SaveAs("AddingDataTableAsWorksheet.xlsx");
}

static DataTable GetTable(String tableName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.TableName = tableName;
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("Dec", typeof(decimal));

    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, 123m);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, 123.4m);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, 123.45m);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, 123.456m);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, 123.4567m);
    return table;
}
```